# How to get/copy pixel coordinates or rgb values from 2d image, in compositor editor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, coordinates

Many times, i need to get and copy pixel coordinates (as well as rgb values) from the composite 2D image in the backdrop or image viewer. i can see it from the image editor by clicking in the image preview, but as soon as i release the mouse, these data are not shown anymore.

[image]

Is there any way to get these data and copy them?
Need something fast to process (CTRL+C ideally) from the gui.

If not available in the last 3.3x blender release, maybe an addon is already exists, none as i know.

thanks

Comment: I don't have an answer, just to keep it visible you can Search for "image.sample" ... also for pixel coordinate you can switch to Mask (type view) by click you can position 2D cursor, under Properties (N) > View > 2D Cursor you can see x/y coordinates ... but yes - someone who is pythons could to know how to let those infos print into Console editor or so ... BTW to pick a colour - you can easily by pressing E above colour field in any move above image and click.

Comment: that´s right, the color picker in the toolbar (T) serves this purpose of copying color value. could be an option to add a tool to copy coordinates too